# Ordenar consulta por relevância MYSQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, match, full-text

como poderia fazer a consulta abaixo ser ordenada por relevância e depois por data?

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare(
"SELECT `id`, `titulo`, `foto`, `descricao`, `slug`, `data`, '' as `local` FROM `noticias` WHERE MATCH (`titulo`, `descricao`) AGAINST (?)
UNION
SELECT `id`,  `titulo`, `foto`, '' as `descricao`, `slug`, `data`, `local` FROM `galeria` WHERE MATCH (`titulo`, `local`) AGAINST (?) ORDER BY `data` DESC"
);
```

Atualmente está ordenando por data, mas queria por relevância de acordo com a busca.

Exemplo:

> Atualmente se eu pesquiso "Festa da Maria" está aparecendo assim:

1. Festa da Maria 12/09/2018
2. Festa Qualquer 10/09/2018
3. Festa do João 10/08/2018
4. Festa da Maria 10/07/2017

> Queria que ficasse assim:

1. Festa da Maria 12/09/2018
2. Festa da Maria 10/07/2017
3. Festa Qualquer 10/09/2018
4. Festa do João 10/08/2018

Comment: não seria então `order by titulo, data DESC`?

Comment: Tentei, mas não deu certo não.

Comment: [`ORDER BY relevance DESC`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6305108/1284458) pode te ajudar... porem ele vai ordenar o primeiro result_set separado do segundo

Comment: @fernandosavio não consegui fazer funcionar, pois no outro exemplo era apenas 1 tabela e não duas como estou fazendo.

Comment: Pois é, ele ordenaria apenas um select... para ordenar os dois juntos acho que teria que transformar teus unions em uma subquery e ordenar no select mais de fora.

Comment: @fernandosavio esse link aqui tem a resposta (eu acho), mas não consegui adaptar para a minha consulta. POderia me ajudar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018577/mysql-fulltext-search-relevance-across-multiple-tables

Comment: Na verdade o que eu disse é exatamente o que o @MatheusRibeiro postou como resposta. Ele transformou a tua query em uma subquery e ordenou "por fora" da subquery

Comment: A única diferença é que na resposta que tu linkou existe um campo `relevance` que adicionado ao select e é usado para fazer a ordenação.

Comment: Sim, mas como eu disse pra ele, eu preciso ordenar por relevancia do resultado e não necessariamente em ordem alfabética. Por ex, eu preciso "festa rosario" se eu ordenar por ordem alfabetica esse resultado podera vir depois de "festa legal" pois os 2 tem o termo festa e por ordem alfabetica o resultado "festa legal" viria primeiro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você teria que fazer algo +/- assim:

```
SELECT `id`, `titulo`, `foto`, `descricao`, `slug`, `data`, '' as `local`, 
MATCH (`titulo`, `descricao`) AGAINST (?) AS relevance 
FROM `twd_noticias` 
WHERE MATCH (`titulo`, `descricao`) AGAINST (?) 
UNION 
SELECT `id`, `titulo`, `foto`, '' as `descricao`, `slug`, `data`, `local`, 
MATCH (`titulo`, `local`) AGAINST (?) AS relevance 
FROM `twd_galeria` 
WHERE MATCH (`titulo`, `local`) AGAINST (?) 
ORDER BY relevance + data DESC
```

Comment: Desse jeito da isso <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in

Comment: Verifique minha alteração!

Comment: Mesmo erro, creio que seja por causa do $mysql -> prepare

Comment: Na minha resposta estou usando aspas simples em cada field e não coloquei o script entre aspas duplas... Você configurou certinho no teu fonte? Ou apenas copiou e colou o que fiz?

Comment: Deixei o geral dentro da aspas duplas e não funcionou.

Comment: $query = $mysqli->prepare( "select * from (SELECT 'id', 'titulo', 'foto', 'descricao', 'slug', 'data', '' as 'local' FROM 'noticias' WHERE MATCH ('titulo', 'descricao') AGAINST (?) UNION SELECT 'id',  'titulo', 'foto', '' as 'descricao', 'slug', 'data', 'local' FROM 'galeria' WHERE MATCH ('titulo', 'local') AGAINST (?)) as tabela ORDER BY titulo, data DESC");

Comment: Rode esse select diretamente no seu banco de dados e veja se funciona corretamente.

Comment: Encontrei o erro, porém não está ordenando corretamente. Precisava que ordenasse de acordo com a relevancia da busca e não necessariamente em ordem alfabética crescente ou decrescente.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83082/discussion-between-frederico-moreira-and-matheus-ribeiro).

Comment: Vlw Matheus. O resultado agora está satisfatorio